# How to reset css keyframe animation without moving the html element

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I am trying to manage my website navigation with css animation keyframes (I like the effect I achieved, I know it's not the most effective way). I move the contents of my page via css keyframe animation when the user clicks on one of the navigation links.

```
//jQuery

 $('#home').click(function() {




        $("#Home-Content").addClass("Home-Content");

});


// css

.Home-Content {

   animation: fall  7s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

And the animation works perfectly, however, I cannot play the animation twice, and if I remove the class from the html element to reset the animation, the element moves from its position. Is there a way I can reset the animation, without the html element returning to its original position?

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: Maybe you can create a class just with the animation rules. And put the final positioning at the element class.

Comment: @netoguimaraes Can you give an example? :) I'm not exactly sure what you mean.

Comment: Could you post a jsfiddle to help me get in context?

Comment: @netoguimaraes Yes, im about to post it

Comment: @netoguimaraes  https://codepen.io/cold2stonefire/pen/xrrBNZ

Comment: @netoguimaraes That's how my transition works, but when I remove the class for a reset, the content moves as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution for inner nav using `Transition` instead of `Animation` style.
With a container where you put all your pages, div after div, you can move all pages on Y axis by sliding the container itself. Transition let you slide them in smooth way.

https://jsfiddle.net/nesquimo/1xy00039/1/

**HTML**

```
<section class="container">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" data-page="1">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-page="2">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-page="3">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div id="scroller" class="scroller">
    <div id="page1" class="pages"></div>
    <div id="page2" class="pages"></div>
    <div id="page3" class="pages"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
.container{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.scroller{
  z-index: 100;
  transition: transform .6s ease;
}
.pages{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

#page1{ background: blue;}
#page2{ background: orange;}
#page3{ background: green;}

nav{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
}
ul{
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center
}
li{ margin: 0 1em; }
a{ color: black; }
```

**JS**

```
var pages = document.querySelectorAll('[data-page]');
var scroller = document.getElementById('scroller');
var pagesCount = pages.length;

for(var i = 0; i < pagesCount; i++){
  (function(i){
    pages[i].addEventListener('click', function(e){
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();

      var dist = (i * 100) / pagesCount;
      scroller.style.transform = 'translate3d(0,-'+ dist +'%, 0)';
    });
  })(i);
}
```

Comment: Happy to help you. Maybe you should valid the answer in order to close the question and help other people who have the same kind of question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
animation-iteration-count: 2 (no. of times you want to run animation)
Hope this helps!